# Uploading to google app engine bucket and marking file as a public files

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, cdn

It seems pretty straight forward to upload files to your preexisting google storage bucket.

```
gsutil cp foo.txt gs://<bucket-name>
```

However do I make my file be publicly available?

[image]

So one is publicly available other is not. 
How do I change this programmatically, without having to do it from the web console?

And is it smart idea to use google cloud storage as a CDN for you website, hosted on google app engine too?

Comment: what programming language do you use btw? and which client library?

Comment: `gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://<bucket-name>/foo.txt` will make the object readable by anybody on the internet (as for programming language, `gsutil` is a command-line thingy, so the language would typically be bash, cmd.exe, or some other shell one -- non-shell languages offer other APIs that are usually preferred when programming in such other languages).

Comment: @IgorArtamonov well ideally ruby, but I don't think it's supported right now, but bash is fine too.

Comment: @AlexMartelli thanks for the response I'll go ahead and try that now. Wish I can do it in ruby, because I'm trying to do it in automated process but bash is fine for now. Is this storage meant to be used for CDN?

Comment: @Remember_me, to quote https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration, "Google Cloud Storage behaves essentially like a Content Delivery Network (CDN) with no work on your part because publicly readable objects are, by default, cached in the Google Cloud Storage network".  And sure you can do it in Ruby, see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/storage/v1 -- in the future, I recommend you tag your Q as "Ruby" if it's about Ruby!-)

Comment: thanks @AlexMartelli would you like to add an answer, bash is fine for now. That worked for me. I'm also taking a look at the ruby api, thanks. And I edited the tag

Comment: @Remember_me, good idea, made the above content into an answer, thanks for reminding me to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://<bucket-name>/foo.txt` will make the object readable by anybody on the internet (`gsutil` is a command-line thingy, so it would typically be used via `bash`, `cmd.exe`, or some other shell language -- non-shell languages offer other APIs that are usually preferred when programming in such other languages).

As for the CDN sub-question, to quote http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration:

> Google Cloud Storage behaves essentially like a Content Delivery
>   Network (CDN) with no work on your part because publicly readable
>   objects are, by default, cached in the Google Cloud Storage network.

Lastly, as the OP indicated specific interest in accessing GCS from Ruby, see http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/storage/v1 for the purpose.